# Ensure List of elements ordered by field in element

Tags: collections, java-8, guava, method-reference

Using [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) it is possible to ensure ascending ordering this way:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Ordering;
import io.predictor.dao.ohlcv.OhlcvHm;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

assertThat("Ordered by age", Ordering.natural().isOrdered(
    employees.stream().map(Employee::getAge).collect(toList())));
```

It is strange for me that Guava (for all its close relation to Java lambdas) does not provide easy solution for such cases. 
Of course I can write some helping methods and wrap it but maybe someone has already done it in libraries. Is there an easiest method doing it? Something like:

```
XLibrary.isOrdered(employees, Employee::getAge);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
assertThat("Ordered by age", 
           Ordering.from(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getAge)).isOrdered(list);
```

or

```
assertThat("Ordered by age", 
           Ordering.natural().onResultOf(Employee::getAge).isOrdered(list);
```